Convert VersionedTransaction to Transaction
Is there a way to convert a VersionedTransaction to a Transaction? I need to combine two transactions into one but with the type of VersionedTransaction it can't be done. Any help?

Here is how you can convert a versioned transaction to a legacy transaction
// your versioned transaction
    let tx: VersionedTransaction = ....;

    let txInstructions = TransactionMessage.decompile(tx.message).instructions;
    const legacyMessage = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: signer.publicKey,
        recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions: [...txInstructions],
    }).compileToLegacyMessage();

    const legacyTx = Transaction.populate(legacyMessage); 

    const txId = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, legacyTx, [signer]); 

I am unsure of your needs, but instead of converting the tx to a legacy tx, you could pull the instructions to a single versioned transaction and send that.

    let tx1Instructions = TransactionMessage.decompile(tx1.message).instructions;
    let tx2Instructions = TransactionMessage.decompile(tx2.message).instructions;

    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: signer.publicKey,
        recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions: [...tx1Instructions, ...tx2Instructions],
    }).compileToV0Message();
 
    let tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
    const txId = await connection.sendTransaction(tx);
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txId}?cluster=devnet`);


I want to combine the VersionedTransaction with another Transaction and send them both. VersionedTransaction is from swap API and another one is normal Transaction.
